# Relating the bounds of these two similar functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have that {z$_{n}$}$_{n}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ z$_{n}$ = 0.

I want to relate the bounds of log(1+z$_{n}$) and log(1+|z$_{n}$|) so that I can show that $\sum$|log(1+z$_{n}$)| converges if and only if $\sum$log(1+|z$_{n}$|) converges.

Please provide me a hint or something but don't solve the problem in entirety.

Comment: Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $\frac {log(1+z)} {z}$ converges to 1 as z goes to 0. It becomes evident that either series converges if and only if $\sum |z_n|$ converges.